# Can anyone help me make a for loop for this code?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

I have this code which is rather repetitive, so I was wondering whether someone could help me convert it into a loop in JavaScript (including an array if necessary), as my knowledge of them is very limited.
Here is the code:

```
//9 Carat Gold
document.getElementById("9CGGBP").innerHTML = (data[0] * data[4]).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("9CGUSD").innerHTML = (data[0] * data[5]).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("9CGEUR").innerHTML = (data[0] * data[6]).toFixed(2);

//18 Carat Gold
document.getElementById("18CGGBP").innerHTML = (data[1] * data[4]).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("18CGUSD").innerHTML = (data[1] * data[5]).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("18CGEUR").innerHTML = (data[1] * data[6]).toFixed(2);


//Silver
document.getElementById("SGBP").innerHTML = (data[2] * data[4]).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("SUSD").innerHTML = (data[2] * data[5]).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("SEUR").innerHTML = (data[2] * data[6]).toFixed(2);

//Platinum
document.getElementById("PGBP").innerHTML = (data[3] * data[4]).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("PUSD").innerHTML = (data[3] * data[5]).toFixed(2);
document.getElementById("PEUR").innerHTML = (data[3] * data[6]).toFixed(2);
```

If this does not comply with the question regulations, feel free to remove it, but I am just seeking help. :)

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance! :D

Comment: is `data` a fixed length array? are those all the ids that are going to be needed? are those ids going to always be used with those `data` indexes ie is 9CGGBP going to always be for `data[0]` and `data[4]`

Comment: Sometimes trying to optimize things we just add unnecessary complexity. I thinkl this is exactly the case.

Comment: @ederpsampaio - OP's current code is more than coincidentally repetitive--there's a genuine pattern here. OP is right to ask about how to condense this. While it may add logical complexity, it will likely improve maintainability. (On the other hand, if performance was an issue, unrolling loops like this is would be a good idea provided common subexpressions like `data[0]` were factored out.)

Comment: @Kieran Please note that any of the code in the answers will be less efficient AND harder to read than the code in your question above.

Comment: I am aware that it may decrease performance, but this is a project for my Computer Science coursework, so complexity means more marks. In this instance, I believe that a for loop is more complex that the extended list which I posted in my original code. Thank you for the advice though, and thank you for all of the answers! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
var types = ["9CG", "18CG", "S", "P"];
var currencies = ["GBP", "USD", "EUR"];

for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < currencies.length; j++) {
    document.getElementById(types[i] + currencies[j]).innerHTML = (data[i] * data[4 + j]).toFixed(2);
  }
}
```

Comment: Dang. You beat me by 2 seconds! +1 to you.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works perfectly! Is there anywhere which you would recommend me reading about loops to get a better understanding?

Comment: This is a very good answer, but I'm mad that you stole my code before I finished writing it, down to the variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
var prefixes = ["9CG", "18CG", "S", "P"],
    currencies = ["GBP", "USD", "EUR"],
    prefix, baseData, i, j;

for (i = 0; i < prefix.length; ++i) {
    prefix = prefixes[i];
    baseData = data[i];
    for (j = 0; j < currencies.length; ++j) {
        document.getElementById(prefix + currencies[j]).innerHTML =
            (baseData * data[4 + j]).toFixed(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: You missed a comma at the end of the line declaring the `currencies` array.

Comment: @newbiedoodle - Fixed. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

This should work, though honestly it makes the code harder to read and probably slower.

I would rather do it the way you have it, but here you go:

```
var idArray = ["9CGGBP","9CGUSD","9CGEUR","18CGGBP","18CGUSD","18CGEUR","SGBP","SUSD","SEUR","PGBP","PUSD","PEUR"];
for (var i=0; i<12; i++) {
    document.getElementById(idArray[i]).innerHTML = (data[Math.floor(i/3)] * data[i%3+4]).toFixed(2);
}
```